# Using variables to store custom functions in a class

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm trying to make a class with some member variables that store or point to functions, or can be assigned a different behaviour which describe how to process other variables in the object.

```
class C {
    int n;
    void *data;
    // buidData: It allocates and stores data using the data pointer avobe to be processed later
    // processData: It does something with n and data

    public:
    void run(); //performs processData 
    // setters needed...

}
```

Here, `buildData` and `processData` could be just methods that do one thing: Maybe `buildData` allocates memory for a double and `processData` stores n^3 in the allocated position.

What I need for them is to be variables: some function-type variable, or function pointer which can somehow be assigned a code describing its behavior. So, instead of just calculating n^3 always, it could perhaps build a random list of n elements that removes duplicates when the process function is run, store a file name read from console and process a file with that name or... pretty much anything (or nothing at all).

So, in concept, I want empty methods whose behavior I can borrow easily using previously existing code in a parametric fashion.

I strongly feel C++ is giving me the tools to do it (lambda functions, function pointers, the function type in `<functional>...`) but for some months I didn't get there yet.

How can I possibly declare `buildData` and `processData` and how should one assign them their "job" in an elegant way?

Comment: `void *` is not a valid solution to any C++ problem.

Comment: Do the functions have the same parameter? or do they have random parameters and variable number of parameters?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have found lots of not-solutions.  I was just trying to picture what my goal is, and i'll be happy to use any propper c++ tech, once i learn how to use it. 

Mentioning a generic pointer to any kind of data is an analogy to what i aim for with functions, but any suggestion to improve the question will prompt me to edit it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Surt The idea is that they can be guided by data stored in the object, one way or another. My aproach was to think about them as void methods that can accces a couple or member variables. But regretly my c++ knowledge is quite shallow, so it may not be the best way.

If it allows me to take preexisting code and adapt it so the class can observe what is doing we can go with fixed prototypes, or something enterely flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).  You can assign default functions in the same way that you might assign default values to primitive members, but then override the functions in `C`'s constructor if necessary.

Alternatively, you could go with the classic OOP solution where `C` is a base class with default behaviors, but users are allowed to extend into a child class that `override`s the behavior for `buildData` and `processData`.

Comment: Yes. That std::function route is what I see more promissing, but I don't seem to find the right syntax, to put it in to use. Could you please give me any hint on how I would create an object of the class that overrides the default behavior of buildData and/or processData?

The second solution could really work for the actual problem I want to tackle, but It'll, make me rewrite those methods through inheritance and make a new subclass for each object I need. 

The idea is I can declare an object and assign it some tasks so the rest of the class can extract info from those tasks performance.

Comment: Also. The second route won't allow me to learn more C++ tech, which is itsef a goal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I finally found a way to make it work with std::function. But my first aproach is quite ugly and clunky (using lambda expresions matching the class member prototype that call the real function). I would like to improve that.

Should I update this question or publish a different one?

Comment: @xcaliph I would ask a new question.  If the code is working now, you might get more helpful responses over at [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).